# Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, fluttermap

Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /Users/apple/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/FlutterLocationService.kt: (124, 1): Class 'FlutterLocationService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: /Users/apple/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/FlutterLocationService.kt: (258, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to this location -> Users/apple/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org, cut/move the location-4.3.0 folder and paste it somewhere, run your application afterwards and it should solve the problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me, just deleted all the folder packages listed in the error.

Comment: doesn't solve the error for me

Comment: Did not work for me. These errors started happening after I upgraded to Flutter 3

Answer (score 5):

I think this is due to version mismatch with the package. In my case, it was solved by changing the package version to latest version.

```
- location: ^4.3.0
+ location: ^4.4.0
```

Comment: it works for me, updating version and adding minSdkVersion to 20, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you have added location permissions in AndroidManifest file.
if not, add these permissions in main -> AndroidManifest.xml ,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Already added while adding new pulgin(location) in  pubsec.yaml it shows this error

Comment: Then just change the Kotlin version in Android -> build.gradle file.

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' like this.

Comment: it is also same as  ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

Comment: 1. flutter clean
2. Delete android/.gradle

Comment: it still continues also after deleting it adds .gradle again and again

Comment: please share your code snippet

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x_f8i6Xc4d2jwgNMsqCRxbco6GRA4JW4/view?usp=sharing      app file

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did this:
In command line

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

then, inside pubspec.yaml

> upgrade speech_to_text library from speech_to_text: ^5.4.0 to
> speech_to_text: ^5.5.0

Finally, it worked for me

**NB**: *If you encounter any problem, you may update location: x.x.x to location: ^4.4.0*

Comment: im not working in text to speech library in flutter

Comment: Whoops !! I got the same errors with text speech
In that case, just update from location: x.x.x to location: ^4.4.0, merely.