# Is there an error in the speech_to_text package for Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, speech-to-text, pubspec

Before I install the speech_to_text package. Everything works fine.
Once I install the package I cannot start the application on Android any longer and I get the following error message:

```
e: <PathToFlutter>\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\speech_to_text-5.4.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\csdcorp\speech_to_text\SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (81, 8): Class 'SpeechToTextPlugin' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract 
fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: <PathToFlutter>\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\speech_to_text-5.4.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\csdcorp\speech_to_text\SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (627, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
e: <PathToFlutter>\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\speech_to_text-5.4.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\csdcorp\speech_to_text\SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (771, 9): Class 'ChannelResultWrapper' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error(p0: String, p1: String?, p2: Any?): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
e: <PathToFlutter>\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\speech_to_text-5.4.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\csdcorp\speech_to_text\SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (786, 5): 'error' overrides nothing
e: <PathToFlutter>\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\speech_to_text-5.4.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\csdcorp\speech_to_text\SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (789, 30): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':speech_to_text:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             65.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The application is able to run in Web (Google Chrome).

Some of the things I have tried:

1. I have tried to download this package in a brand new Flutter project. The same error occurred.
2. I have tried to manually install the package
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71561688/18725072 ; I could not use the package after I moved it.
4. I have tried different versions of the package: speech_to_text 5.4.3, speech_to_text 5.4.2 and speech_to_text 2.3.0

My goal is to add a speech to text feature on text fields and make use of voice commands. If you need any other information to solve the problem please do let me know!

Edit:
I am using Flutter version 1.0.0;

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId <ApplicatioId>
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Flutter version and what is the version of that package.

Comment: do you use compileSdkVersion 31 ?

Comment: I have added the information